# Defining struct pointer inside struct

Tags: c, multithreading, struct

I got struct like this:

```
typedef struct runnable
{
    /* something */
    struct runnable *next;
} runnable_t;
```

And in some function:

```
int myFun(runnable_t runnable)
{
   /* something */
   runnable.next = NULL;
   pool->first = &runnable;
   pthread_cond_signal(&(pool->myCond));
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&(pool->lock));
}
```

And, inside some other func2:

```
if (pool->first == NULL)
            pthread_cond_wait(&(pool->myCond), &(pool->lock));

printf("%d\n",pool->first);
```

Ok, so: myFunc should set runnable->next to NULL and signal myCond, then i need to use runnable->next inside other function.

The problem is that inside func2: runnable->next is not NULL. I have checked and address of runnable in both functions is same, and other atrr of runnable are alsa correct. Only this 'next' prop. is not. I assume that my definition of struct and 'next' can be reason.

What is diference beeten
`struct runnable_t * next` and 
`runnable_t * next` (if that would be possible)

Is that a problem?

Comment: `myFun` takes a copy of the struct, so any changes you make (like `runnable.next = NULL;`) are done on the copy, not the original. And `pool->first = &runnable;` turns `first` into a dangling pointer once the function exits

Comment: What @UnholySheep says. Basically you don't ever want to pass a struct as an argument, and you pretty much always should write functions that accept a pointer to a struct.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that u don't pass struct by reference in `int myFun(runnable_t runnable)`, so just copy of the struct changes, not the original passed struct

u must change your function behavior into `int myFun(runnable_t* runnable)`, and also change `runnable.` into `runnable->` in the function (`runnable->next = NULL;`)